# 'Buttons' in scroll view with pages

Tags: objective-c

I've got a scroll view with pages, it uses images to display different pages, I'm looking to put buttons on the different pages but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Here is my current code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add the first image (image1) into the last position
    [self addImageWithName:@"image1.jpg" atPosition:0];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2272, 320);
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(568,0,0,320) animated:NO];

    // add the last image (image4) into the first position
    [self addImageWithName:@"image4.jpg" atPosition:5];

    // add all of the images to the scroll view
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        [self addImageWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.jpg",i] atPosition:i];
    }
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
- (void)addImageWithName:(NSString*)imageString atPosition:(int)position {
    // add image to scroll view
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(position*568, 0, 568, 320);
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link for the same functionality

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/

Instead of labels you can add buttons.